# Referenced assembly deploy question

Tags: c#, .net

I have a project A.

A use a library aseembly(B) which referenced another 3rd party library(C).

I know B will be copies to my output directory. I am wondering whether C will be copies too?

Comment: Did you try it?  What happened?

Comment: I tried, yes it copied. but I just want to make sure in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases, yes. If it doesn't, we'll talk about the exceptions :-)